# Question about bitcoin transaction minted time

Tags: transactions, block-interval, mastering-bitcoin

Book "mastering bitcoin" 3rd edition, on page 26, there is one statement as following:
**"Approximately five minutes after the transaction was first transmitted by Alice’s
wallet, a miner finds a solution for the block and announces it to the network."**

My question is why it is "five minutes"?

Answer (score 1):

That's just a model example. The average time between blocks is 10 minutes, while the median is approximately 7 minutes, so 5 minutes is a pretty common time to wait for the next block.